# Segmentation fault while using pointers: No such file or directory

Tags: c, pointers

I am working on a music similarity project using [musly](http://www.musly.org). I am not very familiar with pointers. The below code gives me a segmentation fault, with GDB saying `no such file or directory`:

```
musly_track_analyze_audiofile(mj,"2.wav",0,track+1);
*(tracks+1)=track+1;
```

The above portion causes the error. Note that this error occurs only when I try to analyze the second file (and 2.wav **is** there in the directory).

```
    Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00007ffff7bd5e3e in musly_track_analyze_audiofile (jukebox=0x6211f0, 
    audiofile=0x400cba "2.wav", max_seconds=0, track=0x6029e4)
    at /home/ananthakrishnan/work/musly-0.1/libmusly/lib.cpp:354
354 /home/ananthakrishnan/work/musly-0.1/libmusly/lib.cpp: No such file or directory.
```

The full program is given below. I think the error is due to pointers.

```
main()
{
musly_jukebox* mj ;
musly_track* track,track2;
musly_track** tracks;
musly_trackid* trackids;
float* similarities;
//const char *j;
int chk,i; 
track=(musly_track *) malloc(5*sizeof(musly_track));
trackids=(musly_trackid *) malloc(5*sizeof(musly_track));
tracks=(musly_track **)malloc(5*sizeof(track));

musly_debug(4);     
mj = musly_jukebox_poweron(NULL,NULL);

musly_track_analyze_audiofile(mj,"1.wav",0,track);
*(tracks)=track;
musly_track_analyze_audiofile(mj,"2.wav",0,track+1);
*(tracks+1)=track+1;
musly_track_analyze_audiofile(mj,"a.wav",0,track+2);
*(tracks+2)=track+2;
musly_jukebox_addtracks(mj,tracks,trackids,1);

musly_jukebox_setmusicstyle(mj,tracks,0);



musly_jukebox_similarity(mj,tracks[2],3,tracks,trackids,0,similarities);


printf("\n%f",similarities);

//musly_jukekox_poweroff(mj);
printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: You don't want to use `malloc()` in C++.  Did you mean to pick the C tag instead?

Comment: The ` no such file or directory` warning is just GDB saying it can't find the program source for "libmusly/lib.cpp".  It has nothing directly to do with the actual SIGSEGV violation.

Comment: @comingstorm i started  w/o  using malloc but it results in : Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x0000000000400a60 in main () at test1.cpp:23
23  *(tracks)=track;

Comment: @paulsm4 But how can it be possible? The function musly_track_analyze_audiofile works perfect for the first time! for the next files this error is shown.

Comment: 1) The point I was trying to make is "disregard the 'file not found'" warning.  2)The fact that "it works perfect for the first time" means that "track" was (probably...) malloc'ed correctly ... but "track+1" points to Never-Never Land.  "malloc()" is probably a mistake. Review the Musly library documentation and see if there's a "better way" to allocate a track...

Comment: You should be aware that `track2`, which appears to be unused, has type `musly_track`, *not* `musly_track *`.  You have used an unnatural grouping of the declarator operators (`*`), suggesting that they group with the types specifier rather than the variables being declared. They do not.

Comment: @paulsm4 yes it was! There was another method for allocating track :) .Thanks for your quick reply

Comment: @TomKarzes .after compiling i understood tht its not musly_tack * then i removed  track2. Thanks for you timely reply!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot just

```
track=(musly_track *) malloc(5*sizeof(musly_track));
```

The size of `track` object depends on many factors. Use `musly_track_alloc` instead.

Comment: This was what i am looking for 2 days.  Thanks bro,God bless u!

Comment: @Ananthakrishnan M A - don't forget to upvote and accept this answer (if you haven't already).  And don't forget to call `musly_track_free()`.

Comment: Are familiar with musly?. if  you can send me that code for similarity checking it would  be of great help! :)

Answer (score 0):

With the help of above comments and answers i executed the program smoothly.
Here is the full corrected code for similarity checking. Hope this help  guys working with musly.

```
#include <musly/musly.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib>
    main()
    {
    musly_jukebox* mj ;
    musly_track* track;
    musly_track* trac[10];
    musly_track* track2;
    //musly_track** tracks;
    //musly_trackid* trackids;
    int trackids[10];
    float similarities[1000];
    //const char *j;
    int chk,i; 

    musly_debug(4);     
    mj = musly_jukebox_poweron(NULL,NULL);
    track=musly_track_alloc(mj);
    for(i=0;i<5;i++)
        trac[i]=musly_track_alloc(mj);
    musly_track_analyze_audiofile(mj,"1.wav",0,trac[0]);

    musly_track_analyze_audiofile(mj,"2.wav",0,trac[1]);
    musly_track_analyze_audiofile(mj,"a.wav",0,trac[4]);
    musly_track_analyze_audiofile(mj,"b.wav",0,trac[2]);
    musly_track_analyze_audiofile(mj,"1.wav",0,trac[3]);
    //tracks=&trac;
    musly_jukebox_addtracks(mj,trac,trackids,3);
    musly_jukebox_setmusicstyle(mj,trac,3);
    chk = musly_jukebox_similarity(mj,trac[3],3,trac,trackids,5,similarities);
    for(i=0;i<5;i++)
        printf("\n%f",similarities[i]);

    //musly_jukekox_poweroff(mj);
    printf("\nchk=%d\n",chk);
    musly_track_alloc(mj);
    }
```